# Zedgraph: How to limit pannings/scrolling on a Yaxis?

Tags: scroll, limit, zedgraph, panning

I have a bar chart that will never go below zero (never go negative), 0 y axis. How do I limit panning/scrolling so that the y0 line is always at the base of the graph? 
The requirement is to not be able to pan below pointy = 0 in view;

Answer (score 2):

Subscribe for `ZoomEvent` or `Scroll` event (you must check which one would be more suitable in your situation).

Create a handler for that event and inside of it, check if current `pane.YAxis.Scale.Min` < 0. If so, change it manually. That should do the trick.